# Node - se ejecuta dos veces un modulo

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

no entiendo por que se ejecuta dos veces el modulo query.js
por lo que lei puede ser que sea por una funcion flecha, pero no encuentro el problema.

```js
const mysql =  require('mysql');

//----------------------------------------------- require mysql 
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM();
const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;
global.document = document;

var $ = jQuery = require('jquery')(window);
//----------------------------------------------- require jquery

const app = {};

//----------------------------------------------- Export query.js


// create connection  
const con = mysql.createConnection({
 host   :  'localhost',
 user   :  'root',
 password  :  '42167895',
 database  :  'nodemysql'
});

console.log('a');

function addButton(){
 // # selector de ID
 // . selector de class


 // Create button1

 const button = '<button id="button1" type="button">Click Me!</button>';
 $('#contain').html(button);
 console.log('test');
 // assigning functionality to button1

/* $(document).ready(()=>{
  $('#button1').click(()=>{
   getTable();
   console.log('Button1');
  });
 }); */
}

console.log('j');

function getTable(){
 // connect
 con.connect((err) =>{
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log('MySql Connected...');
  con.query("SELECT * FROM nodejs", (err, result, fields)=>{
   if(err) throw err;
   console.log(result);
  });
 });
}

app.addButton  = addButton;
app.getTable  = getTable;

module.exports  =  app;
```

```js
const http   =  require('http');
const query  =  require('./query');
const content  =
  '<!DOCTYPE html>'+
  '<html>'+
  ' <head>'+
  '  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>'+
  '  <meta charset="utf-8">'+
  '  <title>test</title>'+
  ' </head>'+
  ' <body>'+
  '  <div id="contain"></div>'+
//  '  <script src="query.js"></script>'+
//  esto es muy interesante,
//  ya que estariamos utilizando mal nodejs,
//  si nosotros queremos usar query.js lo que va a sucedes es un error del tipo :
//   SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Conocer más]
//  buscando en los foros este error aparece por que :
//
//  Cuando el navegador solicita archivos JavaScript como query.js o angular.min.js,
//  su servidor devuelve el contenido de index.html,
//  que comienza con <! DOCTYPE html>, lo que provoca el error de JavaScript.
//
//  la solucion es sencilla y es que como en la carpeta '2do intento', nosotros lo que queriamos hacer era que
//  inregrar nodejs a html, cuando en realidad con node lo que debemos hacer es integrar el html a node
//  ya que node va a ser el encargado de administrar todo ya que es el servidor
//  por lo que ahora nosotros debemos solicitar query.js desde nodejs con un require como bien hicimos arriba
//  con la instruccion const http = require('http');

//  asi que vamos a llamar al modulo query con otro require

  ' </body>'+
  '</html>';


const server  = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
 res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
 
 res.write(content);

// query.addButton();
/* query.getTable();*/

 res.end(); 
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

y

```
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery')(window);
```

hace lo mismo, el primer script ya te está declarando $ como jquery

Comment: seguro que la segunda sentencia esta bien escrita?

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme con su experiencia, la verdad es que estaba con la duda de que si funcionaba el CDN de jquery o si era algo que estaba escribiendo mal, voy a revisar mejor el codigo.